# SmartCard - It seems that Card Manager doesn't exist

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

I have a processor card (Oberthur COSMO), the ATR is 3B 04 68 EA 90 00, but I am unable to select card manager by APDU, I have tried a lot of AID but unsuccessfully. I also tried to select master file but I got the same result.
My question is, Is card manager installed by manufacturer or we can download and install it and how can we install it?

Comment: The CM is usually installed by the manufacturer. Are you sure your card is already prepersonalized? If not, the CM may not be available until you finish the prepersonalization process. This is a common thing for chips by NXP, for example.

Comment: @vojta Thank you. I've searched some information that card issuers are responsible for pre-personalization stage. Is it right? If no, how can I  do this stage? And what ducument can I refer?

Comment: (I am not familiar with Oberthur cards, so please take the following comment as an educated guess, but) some cards react similarily when in error state (e.g. EEPROM failure, internal self-test failure) and manifest this error state in ATR (and your ATR is suspiciously short). Do you have another card to try? What status do you get for `SELECT` APDUs?

Comment: @vlp I have several type of card to try and success with others, but this is my main target card, unfortunately, I can't do any thing with this except to ATR reception. when I selecting SELECT APDU, I receive 6F08 SW.

Comment: @MạnhHùng Pre-personalization can be done by the vendor or by the issuer. You should contact the vendor - the pre-personalization process is usually kept secret and the documentation is distributed upon NDA.

Comment: Thanks BRO! :) ...................................

Comment: Which AID's did you actually try? There should be `A0000000030000` for older cards and `A0000001510000(00)` for newer cards (the first one uses a Mastercard RID (3) while the other has a GlobalPlatform RID (151h). The last `00` for the AID (between parentheses) depends on the implementations, some are correct others aren't, although generally the *shorter* AID's should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Card manager is usually installed by manufacturer. You need to contact to them to know the AID, or to get document to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try `A0 00 00 00 77 01 00 70 0A 10 00 F1 00 00 01 00` as a cardmanager AID.

Comment: @vojta For what? I've picked it up on the net somewhere.